# Why do I always get the same value as the result in a CNN in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, classification, conv-neural-network

Here is my code

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('augmented_data.csv')
dataset = dataset.sample(frac=1)

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,6,5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6,16,5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1024144, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84,1)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 1024144)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    print(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x   

files_read = 0
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize(1024),
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

# device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available else 'cpu')
device = torch.device('cpu')

# model = ConvNet().to(device)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

results = []    
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    try:
      image = load_img('padded_images/' + row['image_name'] +'.jpg')
    except:
      image = load_img('augmented_images/' + row['image_name'] +'.jpeg')

    files_read += 1

    input_tensor = preprocess(image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0).to(device)

    if files_read <= 80 * len(dataset) // 100:
        output = model(input_batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        y = torch.tensor([[float(row['target'])]]).to(device)
        loss = criterion(output, y)
    
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    else:
        model.eval()
        output = model(input_batch)
        results.append([1.0 if output[0][0].double() > 0.5 else 0, float(row['target'])])
```

So i am using pytorch CNN to classify 60k images in 2 classes. When i print the output after the model has trained, whatever the image as input, the ouput is always "tensor([[0.6384]], grad_fn=)". Always the same value. So it predicts only 1 (because it's greater than 0.5). The thing is, when i print the ouput while training, the results vary (16, 1 , 0, 4 ,0.6 etc) but when i print the output (with the same model but not trained) the results don't vary that much (0.5, 0.51, 0.49 0.52, 0.55). So I think it's safe to say that it is converging to a single value. I just don't know why. what could i do differently?

Comment: For a binary classification task, you should be using [BCE](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) instead of MSE. Also what were you trying to do with `transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])`?

Comment: i saw the normalize used in transfer learning examples and i used it. i will change the mse to bce, but still i don't understand why my model can't evaluate correctly

Comment: you have a linear layer of size `1024144`x`120`. Are you sure about it? do you understand what this means?

Comment: Yeah, my images are very big so i need this many inputs to that layer. I think it's correct. I don't think the problem is there

Comment: Your code shows that you train your model for only one epoch.. So it's barely trained when you evaluate it. Can you try with (many) more epochs ?

Comment: This is true but even an untrained network wouldn't predict the exact same value for every image i feed it right? It makes me think that there is a bug in my code, i just can't find it

Comment: **(1)** you should normalize using your dataset's statistics (mean & std) instead of `0.5`. **(2)** the point of using a CNN is **weight sharing**. Consider reducing your input shapes and reduce dimensionality with your `nn.Conv2d`s, which will lower the number of neurons on your FC layer. **(3)** I don't think there's anything wrong with your prediction being similar when using an untrained model: your model's parameters are random on init. **(4)** make sure you are not showing the prediction for the same image on evaluation.

Comment: my models parameters are random on init so the predictions shouldn't be also random? they are really close together

Comment: you say "the results don't vary that much (0.5, 0.51, 0.49 0.52, 0.55)", so they do vary, and it's likely this variation is just random fluctuation around the maximum likelihood for the distribution of the weights of your network. Given that you have hundreds of millions of parameters, in your linear layers, it is not at all an unlikely behavior

Comment: The problem is that they vary this much in the beginning but after 1 epoch the network produces the exact same number whatever the input. it's like it's trained to produce only that number. and i would train it for more epochs but i would like to be absolutely certain that it will work before i start it, because it's gonna take 2 weeks at least